# Get only the longest match from the groups in regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have various strings like '10001110110', '10000', '100001', '00011','0001', '111000' etc..

I need to find out the longest possible combination of 1s with no or 1 zero in between.

I have got a regex like this - `(?=(1+01+))`

But its not returning a group where there is no leading or trailing one.

I want to regex to consider this case too.

Currently its returning all groups
Eg. if the input string is '10110111' it returns 3 groups

`{null, 1011}`, `{null, 110111}` and `{null, 10111}`

I want my regex to return only 1 match with the longest combination. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Pure regex solution cannot check length. Get all the relevant matches and post process to find the one with max length.

Comment: Try `Regex.Matches(<input>, "1+01+").Cast<Match>().Concat(Regex.Matches(<input>, "01+").Cast<Match>()).Concat(Regex.Matches(<input>, "1+0").Cast<Match>()).OrderByDescending(item => item.Length).FirstOrDefault()?.Value`

Comment: This does not work on '1011111011111'. it should return 11111011111 but it returns 1011111

Answer (score 2):

For the following rule:

> I need to find out the longest possible combination of 1s with no or 1
> zero in between.

you can capture 1+ times a `1`, and then optionally match `0` followed by again 1+ times a `1` in the lookahead assertion.

```
(?=(1+(?:0?1+)?))
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6ZQOXm/1) | [C# demo](https://ideone.com/db4OSf)

To get the longest result, you can process the matches, and then sort by the length of the string, and then get the first result from the collection.

```
string pattern = @"(?=(1+(?:0?1+)?))";
string input = @"10001110110 10000 100001 00011 0001 111000 101110111011011";

var result = Regex.Matches(input, pattern)

.Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value)
.OrderByDescending(s => s.Length)
.FirstOrDefault();

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Output

```
1110111
```

Comment: Your version would also recognize strings like `11010111`; you should use `?` instead of `*` after the non-capturing group to ensure it can only be applied zero or once.

Comment: @MKloster Yes, you can make it optional indeed using a question mark if there should be only 1 optional part.

Comment: For a string '101111101111' it returns only '1011111' which is not the longest. Also it does not return '1111101111' which is the longest.

Comment: @Archana Then you have to use the second pattern in the answer `1+(?:0?1+)*` SEe https://regex101.com/r/sNXsD7/1

Comment: that returns the string with multiple zeroes as it matches 101110111011011. I need a string with only 1 zero in between..